# Why will this config file which works on an EC2 instance not work on elastic beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So I have the below kue.config file that works (ie runs fine) on my EC2 instance, not work when I try to use it as an .ebextension on Elastic Beanstalk?

```
    description "start kue server"

    start on filesystem and started networking
    stop on shutdown


    script
      touch /var/log/forever.log
      touch /var/log/stat_out.log
      touch /var/log/stat_err.log
      rm /var/log/forever.log
      rm /var/log/stat_out.log
      rm /var/log/stat_err.log
    NODE_ENV=production forever start --spinSleepTime 10000 -l /var/log/forever.log -o /var/log/stat_out.log -e /var/log/stat_err.log /home/ec2-user/mykue/server.js
    /bin/echo 'Server should be started we ran etc/init/kue.config' >> ../home/ec2-user/wearego
    end script
```

I get the following ERROR:

```
Top level element in configuration file burrokue/.ebextensions/kue.config in application version burrokue3 must be a map. Update the top level element in the configuration file.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing the `.config` files up.

The `kue.config` file you're using is a config file for configuring the Kue service: https://github.com/Automattic/kue

However, the `.config` files in an `.ebextensions` folder is not the same. They are for a different purpose: to configure the Elastic Beanstalk service.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html

The file formats are different.

While they both have names ending in `.config`, the are not the same thing.

In your case, assuming that you already have Kue installed on your Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instances, you can create a `.ebextensions` file that will instruct Elastic Beanstalk to create your `kue.config` file.

Comment: But my kue.config file is not KUE specific. It is a general bash type file that I just happen to be using to start my node server with forever. In this same kue.config file I could have it execute other things besides kue.

Comment: The purpose of `kue.config` is irrelevant: it does not follow the `.ebextensions` file format for `.config` files (which is YAML). So Elastic Beanstalk doesn't know what to do with it.